# Creating Windows Form controls during execution

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I'm sure there's a way to do it, I just haven't been able to work it out for myself and searching the site hasn't shown me what I need to know. Maybe I'm just using the wrong keywords.

I am trying to add controls to a form during execution. I would like to create new controls for the number displayed in a numericUpDown. E.g. if the user inputs 3, 3 controls should be created.

Is it something in Form.ActiveForm.* ?

Thanks.

Comment: What "elements" do you want to create?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of "elements", I think you are referring to "controls".

The general way is:

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.Location = Some Point on your form or container.
this.Controls.Add(textBox);
```

For your extra numbers, just do that in a loop:

```
int topValue = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; i++) {
  TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
  textBox.Location = new Point(0, topValue);
  this.Controls.Add(textBox);

  topValue += textBox.Height + 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a fast response :)

Comment: This works i.e. creates the number of elements as specified in a numericUpDown. However, I would also like for the elements to be destroyed if numericUpDown1.Value drops below the number present on the form. Should I be posting this as a separate question?

Comment: @haapsen That is a different question than the one you posted, one that would create different answers.  I would post a new question and link to this question as a reference.  It sounds like you are venturing into FlowLayoutPanel territory.  Also, call them "controls", not "elements".

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something as simple as this?

```
numericUpDown1.Maximum = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
```

If not, please elaborate.